# How can I retrieve images from Google Sheets in HTML output using sheetrock.js?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, sheetrock

I Can't get images from Google Sheets in the HTML output, by sheetrock.js

I have implemented this code:

```
    var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/edit#gid=0';
    var sheetrockResultsList = Handlebars.compile($('#compileMe').html());

    $('#resultsList').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: 'select A,B,C,D,E',
    callback : makeTable,       
    });

    function makeTable(error, options, response) {
    $(options.user.target).DataTable({
    pageLength: 30,
    lengthChange: false,
    searching: true,
    paging:false,
    scrollY: "60vh", 
    scrollCollapse: true,
    sscrollX: false,
    ordering: false,
    language: {
        processing: "Loading...",
        search: "",
    info: "",
    infoEmpty: "No results",
    infoFiltered: ""
        }
    });}
    </script>
```

which works correctly and generates the expected output for all the data... except for the images included in the sheet!

I've read on Github, that it can be done through a "callback", but I'm a real noob on this and I don't understand how to implement it (!?)

Could someone give me a hand on this... or maybe point me to an example page where this is done and serve me as a reference example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I saw the script of https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock , I thought that the values are retrieved from Google Spreadsheet using the endpoint of the query language. If my understanding is correct, in this case, I'm worried that the image in the cell cannot be retrieved. But, you say `I've read on Github, that it can be done through a "callback"`. So, can you provide the detail of it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for your kindly reply! 

what I've read on Github responds to an issue, for which a user comments that "he can't see the images he has in the sheet"... and the project owner responds verbatim:
"Sheetrock doesn't natively support images, but if you know the data is an image URL, you could use the callback option and manually create an image and append it to the page"

that is exactly my case, since I get the images from their corresponding URLs... but I have no idea how to include that "callback" in sheetrock.js and that is described in the project like this:

Comment: callback
Expects function
You can provide a function to be called when all processing is complete. The function will be passed the following parameters, in this order:

Comment: Error (object): If the request failed, this parameter will be a JavaScript error; otherwise, it will be null. Always test for an error before using the other parameters.

Options (object): An object representing the options of the request. The user property will contain the options you originally provided (useful for identifying which request the callback is for) and a request property with information about the HTTP request to Google’s API.

Response (object): An object containing response data properties:

Comment: .attributes (object): An object containing useful information about the response data, its structure, and its format.

.raw (object): This is the raw response data from Google’s API.

.rows (array): An array of row objects (which are also passed individually to the rowTemplate, if one is provided).

.html (string): A string of HTML representing the final presentational output of the request (which is also appended to the target or jQuery reference, if one was provided).

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, it seems that sheetrock.js uses the endpoint of the query language. And, the query language cannot retrieve the image into a cell. Please be careful about this. About `if you know the data is an image URL, you could use the callback option and manually create an image and append it to the page" that is exactly my case`, in your situation, how is the image URL put into the cell? When the URL is directly put into the cell, you can retrieve the URL as the cell value.

Comment: But, if the URL is put with the formula, unfortunately, the query language cannot retrieve the formula. I'm worried about this. By the way, is your Spreadsheet publicly shared? If the Spreadsheet is publicly shared, I thought that when an API key is used, the image URL might be able to be retrieved.

Comment: @Tanaike I get the image by an formula like:
`=IMAGE("http:// domain com/imgs/"&A2:A&"_01.jpg";4;120;120)`
which is inside an arrayformula and this retrieve the corresponding image for each item... ANYWAY, I could chage it to obtain the image's URL, instead the image itself, if it helps! Do you think it would be ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I'm worried that in that case, your goal might not be able to be achieved by sheetrock.js. But you say `I could chage it to obtain the image's URL, instead the image itself`. In this case, how about using it? When you can retrieve the image URL, I think that it will be your expected result. By the way, I apologize for my poor English skill. I have to ask the same question. Is your Spreadsheet publicly shared?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike ! I've temporary shared the link to the source document. Don´t worry about your english... mine is no better. Thanks Google Translate! hehehe
By the way: I've tryed by the image´s URL... but I only get it as text (not even link), at the HTML output

Comment: SOLVED: Instead of using the image's URL, I've changed the formula to give me de complete IMG tag as an output... and VOILA! hehehe
="<img src='http://[domain]/imgs/"&A2:A&"_01.jpg' WIDTH='120' HEIGHT='120'>"
Thank you very much @Tanaike for your interest and kindly support!  =)